# Disable Backup Service in Android Emulator

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, backup, adb, android-emulator

I'm trying to replace sms and contacts database on Android emulator with some other (extracted from other phone).

I've already succesfully pushed files into emulator (using `adb push`), but I have to restart emulator to see if anything changes.

In my log there is statement saying that phone is running form backup:

```
04-23 11:22:00.064: I/SystemServer(81): Backup Service
04-23 11:22:00.135: I/BackupManagerService(81): Found stale backup journal, scheduling
04-23 11:22:00.145: I/BackupManagerService(81):   com.android.inputmethod.latin
04-23 11:22:00.145: I/BackupManagerService(81):   com.android.browser
04-23 11:22:00.145: I/BackupManagerService(81):   com.android.providers.settings
04-23 11:22:00.165: I/BackupManagerService(81):   android
04-23 11:22:00.175: I/BackupManagerService(81):   com.android.providers.userdictionary
04-23 11:22:00.204: I/BackupManagerService(81): Backup enabled => true
```

While watching file system in eclipse I can see that journal file is created in `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases`, grows, then dissapears, and my mmssms.db file (previously pushed by command line) shrinks, which gaves my empty database ;/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command from your PC:

```
adb shell bmgr enable false
```

If you have more than one device or emulator running/connected, you'll need to add the `-s DEVICE` option.

Comment: works fine, thanks! Also I figured out, that with my contacts database it was problem only with google account stored in sqlite (different from this in android emulator). SMS db is still dissapearing, but I have to deal with it later.

Comment: After executing it says: `Backup Manager now disabled`